# R: using scale() to get z-score and merging back?

Tags: r

I have a CSV like so...

```
pid,score
1,3
2,6
3,9
4,1.5
5,5.6
6,10
```

And I can get the z-score using `scale(data$score)`.

But I'm stuck at how to merge it back using the `pid` key so my original data frame would be `pid,score,z`. Any tips for this 101-ish feeling exercise?

Comment: umm.... is this what you want `data$z <- scale(data$score)`

Comment: doh, yeah, that's super obvious :) thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple assignment.

First recreate your data

```
dat <- read.csv(header=TRUE, text="pid,score
1,3
2,6
3,9
4,1.5
5,5.6
6,10")
```

Next, compute the scaled value and assign directly in the data frame.  Since the scaling operation doesn't change the order of your data, this should work:

```
dat <- within(dat, scale <- scale(score))
dat

  pid score       scale
1   1   3.0 -0.86502756
2   2   6.0  0.04552777
3   3   9.0  0.95608310
4   4   1.5 -1.32030523
5   5   5.6 -0.07587961
6   6  10.0  1.25960154
```

---

I am using `within()` to save some typing and improve readability.